# How to run specific test suite in jest-puppeteer

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I wanted to run specific test suite in jest-puppeteer for UI automation. 
I am able to run the specific test using below.

> jest -t test_name

where test_name is from the "it" not from "describe" without quote.

Is there any other cmd to run all the test under describe too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run tests that match this spec name (match against the name in describe or test, basically).

```
jest -t name-of-it
jest -t "name-of-describe"
```